# Im trying to store my nested json file to db but it throws error in index

Tags: json, spring-boot, jsonparser, nested-json

> Im Planed to Store my Nested Json File into postgres db Using java Spring boot But the nested json array part throw a error, What can i do To solve this Error

**Error Is**

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.deepCopy(TypeHelper.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

**My Json Structure is**

```
[{
        "basicInfo": {
           "uniqueFileNo": "xxx",
           "actualOrgid": "3",
           "tRefNo": "xxx",
           "tType": "xxx",
           "tFormContract": "Works",
           "tNoOfCovers": "2",
           "tTenderCategory": "xxx",
           "tNoOfBidOpeners": "xxx",
           "tAllowAutomaticEvaluation": "false",
           "tAllowMultiCurrencyForBoq": "false",
           "creatorName": "xxx",
           "creatorReference": "xxx"
        },
        "multiCurrencyForBoq": "",
        "boqinfo": "",
        "coverinfo": {
           "cover": [
              {
                 "tCoverNo": "1",
                 "tDocDesc": "xxx",
                 "tDocType": "xxx"
              },
              {
                 "tCoverNo": "2",
                 "tDocDesc": "xxx",
                 "tDocType": "mmm"
              }
           ]
        }
     }]
```

**How To fix this Error**

Comment: Is it possible that you would need values of 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2 for `tCoverNo`?

Comment: But **tCoverNo** is  a value Not a Array Index right?

Comment: For some reason it is being used as an array index. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` would not be thrown otherwise.

Comment: **okey bro But  Shall I change the Values to 1 and 2 to 0 And 1? **

Comment: I don't know, but I would test it to see whether the problem reproduces. It's useful to know even if you only change it temporarily.